# Is there an infinite nilpotent group with one Sylow subgroup that is not normal?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, nilpotent-groups

It is known that a finite nilpotent group has every Sylow subgroup normal in it. Does this result generalize to infinite nilpotent groups or not ?

If not, why, what is a counter example?

Comment: What is a Sylow subgroup of an infinite group?  Just a maximal $p-$subgroup?

Comment: I didn't check if that works, but was thinking it might if we consider that it has a maximal subgroup of a certain power of a prime ? Say you can find a subgroup of order $p^m$ but never $p^k$ for $k>m$.

Comment: Well, I'd assume you were talking about (potentially) infinite subgroups.  Anyway, this is a point you need to clarify.

Comment: are you saying we are allowed to define Sylow subgroups for infinite groups? If not then I must delete the question as it makes no sense.

Comment: Oh, it makes sense my way.  Don't know the answer, though.  Never thought about it.  But either way, you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is true, is not very complicated, and is part of Theorem 5.2.7 from Robinson's book "A Course in the Theory of Groups" (2 Edition):

> **5.2.7.** Let $G$ be a nilpotent group. Then the elements of finite order in $G$ form a fully-invariant subgroup $Τ$ such that $G/T$ is
> torsion-free and $Τ = \operatorname{Dr}_p T_p$ where $T_p$ is the
> unique maximum $p$-subgroup of $G$.

$\operatorname{Dr}$ is the notation for the direct product in that book.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: Thanks @Shaun, I'll be aware of that. But I found the question interesting, even though the answer was obvious.